# Histogram with links-own variable

Tags: netlogo

```
links-own [ Variable ]
```

Hello I am trying to find a way to make a histogram based on links-own variable and the number of links as the frequency.

I used the following logic in plot and it's not showing anything

```
histogram [Variable] of links
```

Comment: that's the correct logic. Do you have `reset-ticks` at the end of your setup procedure? Did you set the plot to bars instead of points?

Comment: Yes I did, and also min, mean and max are showing but not the histogram

Comment: Since it's not throwing an error, you must have spelt the variable name correctly. Perhaps have another look at your settings. Do your x min and x max cover the range of values shown with your min/max? Open the pencil again and below the mode (where you set it to bar), is the interval sensible?